# Distributed Tensorflow Using fit_generator()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing

Is it possible to use Tensorflow in a distributed manner and use the fit_generator()? In my research so far I have not seen anything on how to do this or if it is possible. If it is not possible then what are some possible solutions to use distributed Tensorflow when all the data will not fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using fit_generator() is not possible under a tensorflow distribution scope. 
have a lookt at [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data). i rewrote all my Keras ImageDataGenerators to a tensorflow data pipeline. doesn't need much time, is more transparent and quite remarkably faster.